# Understanding lighting for physically based rendering

Tags: physically-based, physics

i wanted to ask if you know the best books or resources to understand light physics. I have heard that Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar's book "Radiance Transfer" is very good. Any other books or suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a full repository with a lot of papers about light transport. There's also a folder named 'theory' where you can get both intro and advanced refs regard light physics. And much more. I'm personally curating this and keeping up to date with latest advancements.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16A6Yj2esRTk0FP-ALr6XfxkGQvTb_1dD?usp=sharing

However here are the main books/papers I suggest to read :

1985 - Physically Based Lighting Calculations For Computer Graphics

1986 - The Rendering Equation

1997 - A Framework for Realistic Image Synthesis

1997 - Robust MonteCarlo Methods For Light Transport Simulation

2011 - The State of the Art in Interactive Global Illumination

2014 - The Path to Path-Traced Movies

Comment: I have already discovered this folder, thank you though.

Comment: Could you include the names and authors of a few papers you feel are most relevant to the question, as part of your answer? Or even the whole list if you have it in a useful format. As it is, this falls under "link only answer" with the issue that it will become useless should you one day delete the folder, or google shuts down their service, etc. I won't flag it as such because it looks like a very useful collection though.

Comment: @Olivier I just added a bunch of paper titles with the year of pubblications to be found easily.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the answer that lightxbulb already gave, you can find a very in-depth explanation of the physics of light and their simulation in the thesis of Eric Veach named "Robust Monte Carlo methods for light transport simulation".

I read it for a class that I took in Computer Graphics and really liked it.

You can find it yourself by searching the web or by visiting this link:
https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/veach_thesis/thesis.pdf